# Tensorflow-keras Image Classifier error while fitting

Tags: python, deep-learning, cnn

I was building an image classifier with TensorFlow but I got stuck while fitting the model. Can somebody help me out?

```
python
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

X = pickle.load(open("X.pickle", "rb"))
y = pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb"))

X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()


model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size= (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size= (2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation(('sigmoid')))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer="adam",
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_split=0.1)
```

Error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-497337dde332> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=3, validation_split=0.1)

~/Downloads/yes/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~/Downloads/yes/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1038       (x, y, sample_weight), validation_data = (
   1039           data_adapter.train_validation_split(
-> 1040               (x, y, sample_weight), validation_split=validation_split))
   1041 
   1042     if validation_data:

~/Downloads/yes/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in train_validation_split(arrays, validation_split)
   1374     raise ValueError(
   1375         "`validation_split` is only supported for Tensors or NumPy "
-> 1376         "arrays, found following types in the input: {}".format(unsplitable))
   1377 
   1378   if all(t is None for t in flat_arrays):

ValueError: `validation_split` is only supported for Tensors or NumPy arrays, found following types in the input: [<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error appears to be related to the type of your input data, may be worth checking for it with `type(X)`.

I would suggest loading pickle with pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

X = pd.read_pickle(r'filepath')
X = X.astype('uint8')
```

Also for info, in your code above you are using the Keras API which is meant to be a high-level API for TensorFlow.

Comment: type(X) is numpy ndarray

Comment: Load with pandas and convert to ui8 `X.astype('uint8')`, see above updated response.

Comment: sorry still no way I am working on linux

Comment: Have you checked your X input is not empty?